# Trying to print more than one letter when user inputs with more than one

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
# these are replaced with regular characters for brevity, but are multi-line
# ascii art strings in the original codebase.
a_ascii_art = "A"
b_ascii_art = "B"

x = input("What would you like to print? ")
if x == "a": print(a_ascii_art)
if x == "b": print(b_ascii_art)
```

I would like for it to be able to print both A and B at the same time when called. But also for it to be in order How do I do that?

Comment: Please include all your code in your question.

Comment: I did click on the link

Comment: @Hylian StackOverflow doesn't allow pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can do this to check if a substring is located in the given string:

```
if "a" in x:
  #do a things
if "b" in x:
 #do b thins
```

Comment: I just got stack overflow how do I put python in it

Comment: Okay so if I type ba it still shows AB, how do I make it go in order

Comment: To post the code type it between two of these ``` then it will be shown with that fancy background.

Comment: To display them in order you have to loop over your input `for letter in x` and then check if that letter is a or b

Comment: I don't know how to loop, I just started last week.

Comment: well you loop over each letter in the input, I suggest you try googling how for loops in python work

Answer (score 0):

You could check if each letter is *in* the user input, rather than checking that it *is* the user input.

```py
if "a" in x:
    print(a_ascii_art)

if "b" in x:
    print(b_ascii_art)
```

Alternatively you could iterate through the user input and check each one. In this case you should probably wrap the "print" code in a function for legibility.

```py
def print_char(ch: str):
    if ch == 'a':
        print(a_ascii_art)
    if ch == 'b':
        print(b_ascii_art)
    # if you have many of these, consider creating a dictionary like
    #   letters = {'a': a_ascii_art,
    #       'b': b_ascii_art,
    #       'c': c_ascii_art,
    #      ... }
    # and instead use dict.get
    #   art = letters.get(ch)
    #   if art: print(art)

for char in x:
    print_char(char)
```

Comment: That works, but what if I want to type B A it doesn't do it in order

Comment: @Hylian think through the logic in your code, I bet you can figure it out :)